# Search in the list for a pattern having special chars

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to search the pattern in list and print it.
i am using regular expression to search the pattern but not working properly
can someone help me

```
import re
p = re.compile('{*}')
str = 'My {noun2} gave me {number1} dollar bill'
list = str.split(' ')
for i in range(len(list)):
    if p.findall(list[i]): 
       print(list[i])
```

I want output to be like below: 
{noun2}
{number1}

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Maybe you want [this](https://ideone.com/Ejx4kR)? Sorry, your question is rather unclear without additional details on what your input can look like. The pattern you used is rather meaningless since it match `}` or `{{{{{{{}` like substrings only. I think you planned to use `{[^{}]*}` regex with `re.findall`

Comment: {[^{}]*} - this has worked for me. thnks wiktor